# EditText with inputType numberDecimal has underlines

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm seeing what I think is strange behavior using an EditText with inputType=numberDecimal.

On my Galaxy Nexus (using Google Keyboard), when I tap into the editText field, often times there's an underline present:

[image]

It almost looks like it could be auto correct, auto complete, or text suggest but that wouldn't make sense for a numberDecimal input type.  I've tried textNoSuggestions and as expected this did not remove the underlines.

When present, these underlines are currently causing me an issue.  I have a textwatcher attached as a listener on the editText.  After tapping into the field, whenever this underline is present and the cursor is positioned as in the screenshot:

1. When a user enters a 2, onTextChanged receives: 0.002.  This is correct.  I then format this number to be 0.02 in afterTextChanged.
2. At this point if a user enters a 3, onTextChanged receives: 0.020023.  This is not correct.  For some reason the "002" is being appended into the editText value before the 3.  This obviously throws off my formatting logic in afterTextChanged.

My textwatcher logic has been working for a long time and only recently starting having this issue.  Anytime I move the cursor around, making the underline go away then I see no issues with onTextChanged receiving the "incorrect" value.

As far as what's changed to make this underline start happening, I believe I've narrowed it down to the Google Keyboard app.  I see this issue when I use Google Keyboard version 1.1.1881.801980.  I uninstalled updates and rolled back to version 4.2.2-573038, and with that version there are never any underlines and therefore no issues with my textwatcher.

So, my questions:

Does anyone know what this underline is supposed to be in a numberDecimal field?  Is it legit or is this a bug?

Bug or not, does anyone know how to prevent this underline from ever appearing when a user taps into the field?

Comment: Please turn off your keyboard dictionary and let me know...It works for me...

Comment: Hi Sri, I'm not sure how to turn off my keyboard dictionary?  I did try going into Settings/Language & Input and turning off Auto-capitalization, auto-correction, correction suggestions, dynamic floating preview, gesture trail, and next word suggestions.  I still see the underline.  I would be nice to know which option is making this happen, but I would need a programmatic solution instead of asking users to change their phone settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the latest update to the Google Keyboard app, version 2.0.18933.905102a.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar issue.  Whenever I get underlined text, my text listener is getting unexpected values for the CharSequence s in onTextChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
  android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I already tried textNoSuggestions.  This inputType can only be combined with the "text" inputType.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with the keyboard remembering state for old input even after setText has been called on the EditText.  I fixed it using the following code to reset the state.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.restartInput(editText);
```